# Cloud Endpoints with Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

What I am trying to accomplish is I want to limit the use of the web service running on Google App Engine to my app users that login with Firebase Auth.

How can I add security rules to the openAPI specification to allow users to request only information of their uuid? So users will just be able to use the web service to get the information about their uuids, if they are logged in to Firebase Auth with that uuid

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to pass along the ID token of your user from the client app to your server over a secure connection. Then on your server you can verify that ID token, and customize data access on the user's identity.

For more on this, see the [Firebase documentation on verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: So I need to handle the ID token verification in the server part right? I cannot do it on cloud endpoints part. If so, is all cloud endpoints doing for me is to block users except the ones logged in with Firebase Auth?

Comment: How can I make sure I send that info in a secure connection? I thought Cloud Endpoints is handling the security for me. Isn't the connection already secure because I am sending the request to a URL created by google?

Comment: I don't know enough about Cloud Endpoints to comment on that. But a secure connection would for example be HTTPS.

Comment: @Mr.Blockchain yes, Endpoints only does the role of authentication in this case. What you're looking for sounds more like authorization. You need to manually filter information by uuid in your code.

Comment: what happened to me is that, it had protected also the kubernetes services, that could not call svc_2_svc inside the cluster, having both of them clusterip, in my opnion it should protect only the dns record of endpoint, the services inside k8s should keep it's own behavior