# Clarification on Firebase auth and Google endpoints security

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an android app that authenticates using Firebase. I would like to access a Google endpoints api. I set arguments to the decorator `@endpoints.api` so that only this app can access it.

I was reading the tutorial at 
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/calling-from-android, 
where it states to use the endpoints service object, I would first have to declare credentials as such,

> credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
>       "server:client_id:1-web-app.apps.googleusercontent.com");

and then pass this credential to the service object builder.

However, since I authenticate with Firebase, this credential object would not work. An attempt to do so would output a `GoogleAuthIOException` error.

I cannot find any information on Firebase credential objects that would work for the service builder's third argument. 
The closest I have come to is 
`AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);`

I was reading up on some possible solutions such as at 
[Cloud Endpoints with Firebase Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948459/cloud-endpoints-with-firebase-authentication), but this solution seems to suggest that I have to set up FirebaseAdminSDK on the endpoints service.

My major query is then this: for Firebase authentication on Android, do I have to pass its id token to the endpoint service which will then verify it using FirebaseAdminSDK as this second link suggests, or can I set up a simple Firebase credential variable to pass into the service object, similar to the example in this post's first link?

Comment: Here is an article about using [Firebase Auth](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/authenticating-users#authenticating_with_firebase_auth) to authenticate endpoints.

Comment: That article is besides the point. Please refer to my last paragraph, my issue concerns the android code.